# Save as mhtml file from selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web, selenium-chromedriver, mhtml

Im trying to save web content as mhtml file.
Im using python selenium in docker enviorement.
I use headless mode and tried to save the file with the save as option, but its didn't worked.
does anyone know how to convert the website content to mhtml format?
tnx alot!

Comment: checkout this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352003/how-to-download-webpage-as-mhtml]

Comment: I sow this, but the crtl s option doesnt worked for me because I use headless mode in docker container in linux enviorment